# Como mapear uma tabela sem PK com entityframework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Galera!! no meu projeto ,estou com dificuldades na hora de mapear uma tabela sem chave Primaria(PK),A aplicacao esta quebrando,quando implemento a tabela no MAP do meu projeto.

```
    public class Configuracoes
{
    public int MaximoFilas { get;  set; }
    public int QtdSenhasEspera { get;  set; }
    public string NomeEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string EnderecoEmpresa { get; set; }

}



 public class ConfiguracoesMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Configuracoes>
{
    public ConfiguracoesMap()
    {

        this.ToTable("Configuracoes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é assim que se mapeia uma tabela que terá apenas um registro.

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
public class Configuracoes
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ConfiguracoesId { get; set; }
    public int MaximoFilas { get;  set; }
    public int QtdSenhasEspera { get;  set; }
    public string NomeEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string EnderecoEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ConfiguracoesController : Controller 
{
    private MeuContexto context = new MeuContexto();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var configuracoes = context.Configuracoes.FirstOrDefault();
        return View(configuracoes ?? new Configuracoes { ConfiguracoesId = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Configuracoes configuracoes) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var configuracoesOriginais = context.Configuracoes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
            if (configuracoesOriginais != null) {
                context.Entry(configuracoes).State = EntityState.Modified;
            } else {
                context.Configuracoes.Add(configuracoes);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(configuracoes);
    }
}
```

Mas respondendo à pergunta original, não é possível criar Models sem PK. A quantidade de bugs simplesmente não compensa insistir na abordagem.