# Como manter sempre 1 registro no BD após inserir com entityframework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo em .NET MVC usando Entity framework, como faço para salvar um dado consultando se existe registro ou não na tabela?
1.Consulta se existe ou nao algum dado na tabela
2.se tiver algum registro, ele adiciona substituindo o elemento anterior so podendo haver 1 registro nessa tabela
3.se nao ele insere normalmente

tem como fazer isso usando entityframework?
meu metodo usado na minha Classe Repositorio

```
      public void Inserir(Configuracoes configuracoes)
    {
        this.Context.Entry(configuracoes).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[É preciso contextualizar a pergunta para que esta resposta faça sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54093/como-mapear-uma-tabela-sem-pk-com-entityframework).

Tem sim. Você deve pesquisar sempre usando [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Se não houver registros, o objeto retornado será nulo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var configuracoes = context.Configuracoes.FirstOrDefault();
    return View(configuracoes ?? new Configuracoes { ConfiguracoesId = Guid.NewGuid() });
}
```

O que muda aqui é que eu não usei um repositório porque o [`DbContext` implementado pelo Entity Framework já é um repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40577/entity-framework-ddd-infra-reposit%C3%B3rio-gen%C3%A9rico/40585#40585). Repare que se o objeto retornado é nulo, crio um objeto novo com uma Id gerada como [`Guid`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%9Anico_Global):

```
return View(configuracoes ?? new Configuracoes { ConfiguracoesId = Guid.NewGuid() });
```

Para saber se a configuração já existe, antes de salvar, repita a seleção sobre o objeto, mas agora sem deixar o contexto observando. [`AsNoTracking()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) faz isso:

```
        var configuracoesOriginais = context.Configuracoes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        if (configuracoesOriginais != null) {
            context.Entry(configuracoes).State = EntityState.Modified;
        } else {
            context.Configuracoes.Add(configuracoes);
        }
```

Se o registro é `null`, é preciso adicionar ao contexto. Senão, basta mudar o estado e salvar.

Comment: Tem como fazer uma pesquisa no banco retornando so 1 objeto?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` cumpre esta função. Traz apenas o primeiro ou traz nulo se não existir.